# Unable to write the 'tool tip' property for the field 'formName[0].Page6[0].MyGroup[0].3'

Tags: livecycle, livecycle-designer

I'm updating a new PDF form in Adobe Livecycle Designer 8.0 and keep getting this error when trying to save as either Acrobat 7 or 8 PDF form(.pdf). The issue occurs after copying/pasting fields from an existing PDF to my new one.

I can get around the error by creating new groups and controls, but it would save some time if I could copy/paste and save. Does anyone have a solution for this?

> Error message output:
>
> Generating PDF Document... Font Service: Default font typeface is
>   Myriad Pro. Unable to write the 'tool tip' property for the field
>   'formName[0].Page6[0].MyGroup[0].3'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'formName[0].Page6[0].MyGroup[0].3' refers to the 3rd item in the Object Binding tab.

This was the default 'Off' radio button in the group of radio buttons I copied over, which was a hidden field. The solution for me was to delete and re-add only these hidden buttons from any groups. All other controls within the group could be copy/pasted and saved with this exception.